# Restream live rtmp stream

Tags: javascript, php, audio, streaming

I have 24 hr rtmp livestream .. i need to restream it but with new html5 language because the old one needs flash player.

I have no idea about streaming .. or if this can be done or not?!!

link of rtmp live stream :

http://www.ertu.org/quran/QuranKareem.html

code source:

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                            flashplayer: "player.swf",
                            title: "Quran Kareem",
                            file: "livestream",
                            streamer: "rtmp://liveRadio.onlinehorizons.net/Qurankareem",
                            image: "photo.jpg",
                            controlbar: "bottom",
                            width: "300",
                            bufferlength:'60',
                            height: "20",
                            autostart: "1",


                        });
                    </script>
                    <!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING -->
```

Thanks

Comment: javascript is not java

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try https://restream.io for that, then copy embed stream link and insert it to you're website

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer

Comment: You can setup stream RTMP to https://restream.io and then embed it inside you're HTML like iframe: https://restream.io/settings/embed-player

More about that: https://support.restream.io/en/articles/3399200-embed-your-stream-on-your-website